# Безопасно использовать Curl для проксирования?

Tags: php, curl, безопасность

Есть ли какие-нибудь уязвимости у Libcurl для PHP?
Если использовать для проксирования сайта. Сайт который проксируется защищен от xss, crfs атак.
Также через curl пропускаются Post-запросы.

P.s. Я знаю, что nginx в этом плане  лучше вариант вместо libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

Всю информацию по уязвимостям можно подчерпнуть из открытых баз. Вот довольно популярные:

- https://vulners.com/search?query=order:published
- https://owasp.org/
- https://www.exploit-db.com/google-hacking-database

> Есть ли какие-нибудь уязвимости у Libcurl для PHP ? Если использовать для проксирование сайта.

Переходим по первой ссылке, вбиваем libcurl и видим список [свежих уязвимостей](https://vulners.com/search?query=order:published%20libcurl). Вот например [эта](https://vulners.com/ubuntu/USN-4466-2):

> Marc Aldorasi discovered that curl incorrectly handled the libcurl
> CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY option. This could result in data being sent to the
> wrong destination, possibly exposing sensitive information.

Это значит, что страница сайта, открытая одним человеком, может внезапно попасть к другому посетителю.